# Acceder a valores dentro de una struct dentro de una union

Tags: c++, struct

Tengo un problema con mi código, tengo una struct dentro de una union y me deja asignarle valores pero al intentar leer el valor o asignarlo a otra variable no funciona pone un valor blanco

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdint>

using namespace std;

typedef union {
    struct{
        uint8_t lo;
        uint8_t hi;
    };
    uint16_t value;
}Register;

int main(){
        Register AF;
        AF.lo = 0xF0;
        AF.hi = 0xF0;

        cout<<AF.hi<<endl;
        cout<<AF.value<<endl;
        return 0;
}
```

la salida del programa es este:

```
frijol@frijolito:~/GameBoyEmulator/src$ g++ test.cpp 
frijol@frijolito:~/GameBoyEmulator/src$ ./a.out 

61680
frijol@frijolito:~/GameBoyEmulator/src$
```

Que puedo hacer para acceder a cada valor de forma independiente sin usar bitwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema ocurre porque intentas imprimir un valor de tipo *uint8_t* con *std::cout*.

La función *std::cout* tiene, entre otras, dos versiones, una que recibe un
*char* y otra que recibe un *unsigned int*. Como *uint8_t* suele ser un alias
de char (definido con un typedef), al llamar *std::cout* con un argumento de
tipo *uint8_t* llama a la versión que recibe un *char*, que imprime un caracter,
y no a la que recibe un *unsigned int*, que imprime un entero sin signo.

Para que llame a la versión correcta, puedes hacer una conversión de tipos usando
el operador *static_cast*:

```
std::cout << static_cast<unsigned int>(AF.hi) << '\n';
```

Answer (score 0):

Las uniones sólo pueden tener un miembro activo a la vez, es [comportamiento indefinido](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comportamiento_indefinido) asignar un miembro de la unión y leer del otro.

Tal y como se puede leer en el [estándar de C++](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/n4849.pdf) (traducción y resaltado míos):

> ### 11.5 Uniones
>
> 1. […]
> 2. **En una `union`, un miembro de datos no estático está *activo* si su nombre se refiere a un objeto cuyo ciclo de vida haya empezado y no haya finalizado**. **Sólo un miembro de datos no estático de una `union` puede estar activo en cualquier momento**, esto es, como mucho se puede guardar el valor de uno de los datos no estáticos de la `union` en cualquier momento.
> 3. […]
> 4. […]
> 5. […]
> 6. **Cuando el operador izquierdo de un operador de asignación implica una expresión de acceso a miembro que nomina al miembro de una `union`, esto puede iniciar el ciclo de vida de ese miembro de la `union`**.

Por lo tanto, este código inicia el ciclo de vida de los miembros `Register::lo` y `Register::hi`:

```
AF.lo = 0xF0;
AF.hi = 0xF0;
```

Y el siguiente código lee información de un dato cuyo ciclo de vida no ha empezado:

```
cout<<AF.value<<endl;
```

Lo cuál es comportamiento indefinido y puede dar lugar al comportamiento que describes.